# Pandas Multiindexing

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Consider the following data frame.

```
    In [3]: idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['2021-02-10', '2021-02-11', '2021-02-12'],
   ...:                                   ['Orders', 'GMV', 'AOV']],
   ...:                                  names=['Date', 'Metric'])
   ...: col = ['Yesterday', 'Yesterday-1', 'Difference', 'Difference-1']
   ...: 
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame('-', idx, col)
   ...: print(df)
                  Yesterday Yesterday-1 Difference Difference-1
Date       Metric
2021-02-10 Orders         -           -          -            -
           GMV            -           -          -            -
           AOV            -           -          -            -
2021-02-11 Orders         -           -          -            -
           GMV            -           -          -            -
           AOV            -           -          -            -
2021-02-12 Orders         -           -          -            -
           GMV            -           -          -            -
           AOV            -           -          -            -
```

For example, I have some values in the *Yesterday* and *Yesterday-1* columns, and  **Difference** column needs to be in a format like this:

```
df.loc['2021-02-11', 'Difference'] = df.loc['2021-02-11', 'Orders] - df.loc['2021-02-10', 'Orders]
```

what actually doesn't work and I need the same for every Metric, how do I do that? Do I create a **for loop** and use **iloc** and go through every metric in order to fill the difference column?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should edit your question for clarity, but I think you need:

```
df['Difference'] = df['Yesterday'] - df.groupby(level=1)['Yesterday'].shift()
```

Comment: Sorry for not being really clear but that worked excellent for me! Thank you so much!